Calculation of discrete path function from discrete vector field?
Context
The paper "Stiffness-based optimization framework for the topology and fiber paths of continuous fiber composites" discusses a "streamline" method of path planning for 3D printing composites it uses the example where in the figure below the evenly spaced vectors in figure a) result in the streamlines in figure b)

The Assumption
The example demonstrates that these streamlines are obtained by finding the minimum of the squared difference between the derivative of the path function $\psi$ and the vetor field $\vec{V}$:
\begin{equation}
     \text{minimize: } I(\psi)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \cdot |\nabla_x \psi-\vec{V}|^2 \, d\Omega 
\end{equation}
I hope im correct in thinking that there is some sort of initial assumption of $\psi$ say for example
$$ \psi = ax + bx^2 + cy + dy^2 $$
and then the algorithm uses some form of gradient descent to find what a,b,c,d are but then this would not scale with complexity since as the vecor field gets more complicated then as does the complexity of $\psi$??
The Question
is there a method of obtaining a discrete version of $\psi$ so that it can be represented as an array of pixels and then the streamlines can be obtained by simply using an interpolated marching squares algorithm, I have a vague impression of how this would be done with a kernel traversing across the vector field adding and subtracting values until the local gradient is equal to the vector field but i am unsure of if this is mathematically sound?
